# Embedded flash not working in any browser

Tags: html, flash, embed

```
<object classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000' width='165' height='37' id='niftyPlayer1' name='niftyPlayer1'>
    <param name='movie' value='audio/niftyplayer.swf?file=/audio/tarantella.mp3&amp;as=0'>
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
    <embed id='niftyPlayer1'
            name='niftyPlayer1'
            src='audio/niftyplayer.swf?file=/audio/tarantella.mp3&amp;as=0'
            width='165'
            height='37'
            allowscriptaccess='always'
            allowfullscreen='false'
    />
  </object>
```

When I manually go to "audio/niftyplayer.swf?file=/audio/tarantella.mp3&as=0", it works fine, it just doesn't work embedded into the page.

Comment: Is <?php echo $poem->audio_file_path; ?> giving it a value?

Comment: What's the final output (after the PHP is evaluated)?

Comment: @miguelSantirso: I modified the question to show the final html output.

Comment: @JoshuaM - yes, I have modified the question to show that

Answer (score 1):

Try replace `&amp;` with `&` :

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="165" height="37" id="niftyPlayer1" name="niftyPlayer1">
            <param name="movie" value="audio/niftyplayer.swf?file=/<?php echo $poem->audio_file_path; ?>&as=0" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="audio/niftyplayer.swf?file=/<?php echo $poem->audio_file_path; ?>&as=0" width="165" height="37" id="niftyPlayer1" name="niftyPlayer1">
                <param name="movie" value="audio/niftyplayer.swf?file=/<?php echo $poem->audio_file_path; ?>&as=0" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
            <!--<![endif]-->
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
```

Comment: It was just &, but I was validating the page, hoping that would help, but that made no difference.

Comment: Did you check `<?php echo $poem->audio_file_path; ?>` value? Is it `'audio/tarantella.mp3'` like string? Or maybe there is `'/'` prepended to path?

Comment: Yes the file path is correct, I am able to right click on it in chrome and open it up and then it works just fine.